# Know relationships between all the tables of database in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I wish to all know how the tables in my database are related to each other (i.e PK/FK/UK) and hence i created a database diagram of all my tables in SQL Server. The diagram that was created was not easily readable and had to scroll (horizontally and sometimes vertically) to see the table on the other end.

In short SQL's db diagram are not UI friendly when it comes to knowing relationships between many tables.

My (simple) Question: Is there something like database diagram which can do what db diagram did but in "good" way?

Comment: see:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168724/generate-table-relationship-diagram-from-existing-schema-sql-server][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168724/generate-table-relationship-diagram-from-existing-schema-sql-server

Comment: Typically any DB with over a 100 tables will look like a spiderweb if you try and show all your tables in one diagram. Why not create several diagrams, each one focusing on a group of logically related tables?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Sometimes, a textual representation might also help; with this query on the system catalog views, you can get a list of all FK relationships and how the link two tables (and what columns they operate on).

```
SELECT
    fk.name 'FK Name',
    tp.name 'Parent table',
    cp.name, cp.column_id,
    tr.name 'Refrenced table',
    cr.name, cr.column_id
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tp ON fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tr ON fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cp ON fkc.parent_column_id = cp.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = cp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cr ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cr.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cr.object_id
ORDER BY
    tp.name, cp.column_id
```

Dump this into Excel, and you can slice and dice - based on the parent table, the referenced table or anything else.

I find visual guides helpful - but sometimes, textual documentation is just as good (or even better) - just my 2 cents.....

Comment: that script is really useful. Helpful when need to take a glimpse of the relationships of all the tables

Comment: is it sql server 2k compatible? it can't find 'sys.foreign_keys' & other tables as well.

Comment: @Pratik: this is for SQL Server **2005 and newer** only

Comment: @marc_s - well thanks, but can you suggest something for sql server 2000 as well?

Comment: @marc_s: Nice query to note down, is there another way for doing this, I mean a bit short query. +1 given for your solution

Comment: @marc_s that is a really helpful script .

Comment: Will this also include views or just tables?

Comment: @John: tables only - views don't have "stored" data - they're just stored queries that will be executed at runtime to fetch data from the underlying tables

Comment: @marc_s - see my response to this post at the bottom!

Answer (score 10):

Just another way to retrieve the same data using INFORMATION_SCHEMA

> The information schema views included in SQL Server comply with the ISO standard definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

[sqlauthority way](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2006/11/01/sql-server-query-to-display-foreign-key-relationships-and-name-of-the-constraint-for-each-table-in-database/)

```
SELECT
K_Table = FK.TABLE_NAME,
FK_Column = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
PK_Table = PK.TABLE_NAME,
PK_Column = PT.COLUMN_NAME,
Constraint_Name = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
INNER JOIN (
SELECT i1.TABLE_NAME, i2.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS i1
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE i2 ON i1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = i2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE i1.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
) PT ON PT.TABLE_NAME = PK.TABLE_NAME
---- optional:
ORDER BY
1,2,3,4
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME='something'WHERE FK.TABLE_NAME='something'
WHERE PK.TABLE_NAME IN ('one_thing', 'another')
WHERE FK.TABLE_NAME IN ('one_thing', 'another')
```

Answer (score 8):

Or you can look at [schemacrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Answer (score 4):

This stored procedure will provide you with a hierarchical tree of relationship. Based on this [article](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/5ec149a1-a808-440c-a5c9-19fb083e4441) from Technet. It will also optionally provide you a query for reading or deleting all the related data.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('GetForeignKeyRelations','P') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROC GetForeignKeyRelations 
GO 

CREATE PROC GetForeignKeyRelations 
@Schemaname Sysname = 'dbo' 
,@Tablename Sysname 
,@WhereClause NVARCHAR(2000) = '' 
,@GenerateDeleteScripts bit  = 0  
,@GenerateSelectScripts bit  = 0 

AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

DECLARE @fkeytbl TABLE 
( 
ReferencingObjectid        int NULL 
,ReferencingSchemaname  Sysname NULL 
,ReferencingTablename   Sysname NULL  
,ReferencingColumnname  Sysname NULL 
,PrimarykeyObjectid     int  NULL 
,PrimarykeySchemaname   Sysname NULL 
,PrimarykeyTablename    Sysname NULL 
,PrimarykeyColumnname   Sysname NULL 
,Hierarchy              varchar(max) NULL 
,level                  int NULL 
,rnk                    varchar(max) NULL 
,Processed                bit default 0  NULL 
); 



 WITH fkey (ReferencingObjectid,ReferencingSchemaname,ReferencingTablename,ReferencingColumnname 
            ,PrimarykeyObjectid,PrimarykeySchemaname,PrimarykeyTablename,PrimarykeyColumnname,Hierarchy,level,rnk) 
    AS 
    ( 
        SELECT                   
                               soc.object_id 
                              ,scc.name 
                              ,soc.name 
                              ,convert(sysname,null) 
                              ,convert(int,null) 
                              ,convert(sysname,null) 
                              ,convert(sysname,null) 
                              ,convert(sysname,null) 
                              ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), scc.name + '.' + soc.name  ) as Hierarchy 
                              ,0 as level 
                              ,rnk=convert(varchar(max),soc.object_id) 
        FROM SYS.objects soc 
        JOIN sys.schemas scc 
          ON soc.schema_id = scc.schema_id 
       WHERE scc.name =@Schemaname 
         AND soc.name =@Tablename 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT                   sop.object_id 
                              ,scp.name 
                              ,sop.name 
                              ,socp.name 
                              ,soc.object_id 
                              ,scc.name 
                              ,soc.name 
                              ,socc.name 
                              ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), f.Hierarchy + ' --> ' + scp.name + '.' + sop.name ) as Hierarchy 
                              ,f.level+1 as level 
                              ,rnk=f.rnk + '-' + convert(varchar(max),sop.object_id) 
        FROM SYS.foreign_key_columns sfc 
        JOIN Sys.Objects sop 
          ON sfc.parent_object_id = sop.object_id 
        JOIN SYS.columns socp 
          ON socp.object_id = sop.object_id 
         AND socp.column_id = sfc.parent_column_id 
        JOIN sys.schemas scp 
          ON sop.schema_id = scp.schema_id 
        JOIN SYS.objects soc 
          ON sfc.referenced_object_id = soc.object_id 
        JOIN SYS.columns socc 
          ON socc.object_id = soc.object_id 
         AND socc.column_id = sfc.referenced_column_id 
        JOIN sys.schemas scc 
          ON soc.schema_id = scc.schema_id 
        JOIN fkey f 
          ON f.ReferencingObjectid = sfc.referenced_object_id 
        WHERE ISNULL(f.PrimarykeyObjectid,0) <> f.ReferencingObjectid 
      ) 

     INSERT INTO @fkeytbl 
     (ReferencingObjectid,ReferencingSchemaname,ReferencingTablename,ReferencingColumnname 
            ,PrimarykeyObjectid,PrimarykeySchemaname,PrimarykeyTablename,PrimarykeyColumnname,Hierarchy,level,rnk) 
     SELECT ReferencingObjectid,ReferencingSchemaname,ReferencingTablename,ReferencingColumnname 
            ,PrimarykeyObjectid,PrimarykeySchemaname,PrimarykeyTablename,PrimarykeyColumnname,Hierarchy,level,rnk 
       FROM fkey 

        SELECT F.Relationshiptree 
         FROM 
        ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT Replicate('------',Level) + CASE LEVEL WHEN 0 THEN '' ELSE '>' END +  ReferencingSchemaname + '.' + ReferencingTablename 'Relationshiptree' 
               ,RNK 
          FROM @fkeytbl 
          ) F 
        ORDER BY F.rnk ASC 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- Generate the Delete / Select script 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @RnkSql VARCHAR(MAX) 

    DECLARE @Jointables TABLE 
    ( 
    ID INT IDENTITY 
    ,Object_id int 
    ) 

    DECLARE @ProcessTablename SYSNAME 
    DECLARE @ProcessSchemaName SYSNAME 

    DECLARE @JoinConditionSQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @Rnk VARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE @OldTablename SYSNAME 

    IF @GenerateDeleteScripts = 1 or @GenerateSelectScripts = 1  
    BEGIN 

          WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                           FROM @fkeytbl 
                          WHERE Processed = 0 
                            AND level > 0 ) 
          BEGIN 

            SELECT @ProcessTablename = '' 
            SELECT @Sql                 = '' 
            SELECT @JoinConditionSQL = '' 
            SELECT @OldTablename     = '' 


            SELECT TOP 1 @ProcessTablename = ReferencingTablename 
                  ,@ProcessSchemaName  = ReferencingSchemaname 
                  ,@Rnk = RNK  
              FROM @fkeytbl 
             WHERE Processed = 0 
              AND level > 0  
             ORDER BY level DESC 


            SELECT @RnkSql ='SELECT ' + REPLACE (@rnk,'-',' UNION ALL SELECT ')  

            DELETE FROM @Jointables 

            INSERT INTO @Jointables 
            EXEC(@RnkSql) 

            IF @GenerateDeleteScripts = 1 
                SELECT @Sql = 'DELETE [' + @ProcessSchemaName + '].[' + @ProcessTablename + ']' + CHAR(10) + ' FROM [' + @ProcessSchemaName + '].[' + @ProcessTablename + ']' + CHAR(10) 

            IF @GenerateSelectScripts = 1 
                SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT  [' + @ProcessSchemaName + '].[' + @ProcessTablename + '].*' + CHAR(10) + ' FROM [' + @ProcessSchemaName + '].[' + @ProcessTablename + ']' + CHAR(10) 

            SELECT @JoinConditionSQL = @JoinConditionSQL  
                                           + CASE  
                                             WHEN @OldTablename <> f.PrimarykeyTablename THEN  'JOIN ['  + f.PrimarykeySchemaname  + '].[' + f.PrimarykeyTablename + '] ' + CHAR(10) + ' ON ' 
                                             ELSE ' AND '  
                                             END 
                                           + ' ['  + f.PrimarykeySchemaname  + '].[' + f.PrimarykeyTablename + '].[' + f.PrimarykeyColumnname + '] =  ['  + f.ReferencingSchemaname  + '].[' + f.ReferencingTablename + '].[' + f.ReferencingColumnname + ']' + CHAR(10)  
                     , @OldTablename = CASE  
                                         WHEN @OldTablename <> f.PrimarykeyTablename THEN  f.PrimarykeyTablename 
                                         ELSE @OldTablename 
                                         END 

                  FROM @fkeytbl f 
                  JOIN @Jointables j 
                    ON f.Referencingobjectid  = j.Object_id 
                 WHERE charindex(f.rnk + '-',@Rnk + '-') <> 0 
                   AND F.level > 0 
                 ORDER BY J.ID DESC 

            SELECT @Sql = @Sql +  @JoinConditionSQL 

            IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@WhereClause)) <> ''  
                SELECT @Sql = @Sql + ' WHERE (' + @WhereClause + ')' 

            PRINT @SQL 
            PRINT CHAR(10) 

            UPDATE @fkeytbl 
               SET Processed = 1 
             WHERE ReferencingTablename = @ProcessTablename 
               AND rnk = @Rnk 

          END 

          IF @GenerateDeleteScripts = 1 
            SELECT @Sql = 'DELETE FROM [' + @Schemaname + '].[' + @Tablename + ']' 

          IF @GenerateSelectScripts = 1 
            SELECT @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @Schemaname + '].[' + @Tablename + ']' 

          IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@WhereClause)) <> ''  
                SELECT @Sql = @Sql  + ' WHERE ' + @WhereClause 

         PRINT @SQL 
     END 

SET NOCOUNT OFF 


go
```

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visio is probably the best I've came across, although as far as I know it won't automatically generate based on your relationships.

EDIT: try this in Visio, could give you what you need http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineering-an-existing-database-HA001182257.aspx

Comment: Yeah Visio won't generate relationships auto. Plus, can visio connect to db?

Comment: Apparently you can!? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineering-an-existing-database-HA001182257.aspx

Comment: Oh yes! Reverse Engg. I did it past. thanks for reminding it again.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is based on @marc_s solution, i just concatenated columns in cases that a constraint is based on more than one column:

```
SELECT
   FK.[name] AS ForeignKeyConstraintName
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(FT.schema_id) + '.' + FT.[name] AS ForeignTable
  ,STUFF(ForeignColumns.ForeignColumns, 1, 2, '') AS ForeignColumns
  ,SCHEMA_NAME(RT.schema_id) + '.' + RT.[name] AS ReferencedTable
  ,STUFF(ReferencedColumns.ReferencedColumns, 1, 2, '') AS ReferencedColumns
FROM
  sys.foreign_keys FK
  INNER JOIN sys.tables FT
  ON FT.object_id = FK.parent_object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.tables RT
  ON RT.object_id = FK.referenced_object_id
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      ', ' + iFC.[name] AS [text()]
    FROM
      sys.foreign_key_columns iFKC
      INNER JOIN sys.columns iFC
      ON iFC.object_id = iFKC.parent_object_id
        AND iFC.column_id = iFKC.parent_column_id
    WHERE
      iFKC.constraint_object_id = FK.object_id
    ORDER BY
      iFC.[name]
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) ForeignColumns (ForeignColumns)
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      ', ' + iRC.[name]AS [text()]
    FROM
      sys.foreign_key_columns iFKC
      INNER JOIN sys.columns iRC
      ON iRC.object_id = iFKC.referenced_object_id
        AND iRC.column_id = iFKC.referenced_column_id
    WHERE
      iFKC.constraint_object_id = FK.object_id
    ORDER BY
      iRC.[name]
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) ReferencedColumns (ReferencedColumns)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) (it's free), this script I just wrote will list every possible path between every table in your database.

Given the following database:

[image]

...the script will produce the following output:

[image]

Or you can set the `longestOnly` flag at the top of the script, and it will just output the longest paths:

[image]

And here's the script:

```
var longestOnly = true;

var pathLists = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (var table in Mapping.GetTables()) {
    var subPaths = new List<string>();
    pathLists.Add(subPaths);
    subPaths.Add(table.TableName);

    Go(table, subPaths);
}

var pathStrings = pathLists
    .Select(p => string.Join(", ", p))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(p => p)
    .ToList();
    
if (longestOnly) {
    pathStrings.RemoveAll(z => pathStrings.Any(i => i != z && i.Contains(z)));
} else {
    pathStrings.RemoveAll(z => pathStrings.Any(i => i != z && i.StartsWith(z)));
}

pathStrings.Dump();


void Go(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaTable table, List<string> paths)
{
    foreach (var association in table.RowType.Associations) {
        var subPaths = paths.Concat(new List<string>()).ToList(); // create a copy
        pathLists.Add(subPaths);
        var subPathTableName = association.OtherType.Table.TableName;

        if (!subPaths.Contains(subPathTableName)) {
            subPaths.Add(subPathTableName);
            var subPathTable = Mapping.GetTable(association.OtherMember.DeclaringType.Type);
            if (subPathTable != null) {
                Go(subPathTable, subPaths);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For a complex database, this can take a surprisingly long time to complete, and will return a surprisingly large list of results. I needed to write this for work, and the end result left me feeling pretty defeated. :)

I couldn't find anything else that would do this, so I'm pretty happy with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

All suggestions thus far have shown relationships between entities via primary and foreign keys. Occasionally, it may be useful to also identify relationships via dependencies. I found the need for this to identify the relationships between views and tables when building network graph visualizations.

```
select distinct
      v.name as referencer_name,
      V.type_desc as referencer_type,
      o.name as referenced_entity_name,
      o.type_desc as referenced_entity_type
from sys.views v
join sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
    on d.referencing_id = v.object_id
    and d.referenced_id is not null
join sys.objects o
    on o.object_id = d.referenced_id
order by referencer_name;
```

The above code results in the following table:

[image: SQL Table Result Screenshot]

This can be further extended, using python, to generate network graphs to visually see linkages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS where 
UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
```

This will list the constraints with `SCHEMA_NAME`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QHdM.jpg)

Comment: This is showing invalid column name in place of Table_name. Please suggest, It will be helpful for me.