# How Can I See the Relations On Sql Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Tried both through Azure Interface and SQL Server Management Studio, didn't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about wanting to see the relationships between tables?

There are a few ways

1. You can use a tool such as Entity Framework, which will visually display everything for you.
2. You can script the table for it to output everything in SQL and from the SQL you can see the relationships.

There are many other ways, some more examples here: [Know relationships between all the tables of database in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094156/know-relationships-between-all-the-tables-of-database-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL databases do not support database diagrams.

You can use "Export Data-tier Application" (includes row data) or "Extract Data-tier Application" (only includes schema), and then restore on a local SQL server to create a database diagram locally.