# List sql table relations using query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have one Employee table in my Database which has relations to different other tables. 
In my application, When a user try to delete one employee which has relational data in other tables, I want to display a list of that tables to the user. 
Can I list all table names which prevents the Employee to be deleted (relational data Tables) using a query?

Comment: You can do with sys tables (check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094156/know-relationships-between-all-the-tables-of-database-in-sql-server ), but in realtime that can be performance botteneck.  I would suggest to return this list manually or let exception thrown having proper rollback mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are foreign keys set up, you should be able to run this stored procedure.

```
EXEC sp_fkeys 'Employee'
```