# Display Relationship Types between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and wanted to create a script that shows me the relationship type (M:N, 1:M, M:1, and 1:1) between two param tables. Ideally, it would accept table name, ID(s) for first table, ID(s) for second table, and then display the relationship between them. I did a lot of search, but most [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094156/know-relationships-between-all-the-tables-of-database-in-sql-server) only focus on FK/PK relations that often don't exist. An example: employeeID, departmentID. And relation between employee and department would be M:1. I use SQL Server, but any SQL should be fine.

Comment: I would recommend that you start with simpler problems, like how many customers have more than 10 orders in December.

Comment: In SSMS you can create a new query, right click and select "Design Query in Editor". From there you can select the tables and see the relationships.

Typically, you would however create your database model first, and then use it as a map. It's rare that the relationships will change after you create the tables, so I can't see a use for this script.

Comment: The **logical relationships** you are talking of are (often) implemented **technology-wise via FK/PK** relations. If those don´t exist, its only meta information known to the db designer but not stored and therefore not readable via script.

Comment: @Daniel there are no FKs/PKs implemented. They exist, but not as FK/PK, they did not enforce it for performance or flexibility reasons.

Comment: @starbyone this does not seem to show me relationship types. there are no FKs/PKs implemented. They exist, but not as FK/PK, they did not enforce it for performance or flexibility reasons.

Comment: Yes, so the relations are not implemented in the system, no way to get them out via script then!

Comment: You could in theory collect all the statements in use over an amount of time via sql profiler and then analyse the joins to reverse engineer some of the structure. That´s what I often do if a customer presents me with a database without proper schema but I am not aware of an easy scripting solution doing that for you ...

Comment: @Daniel It is easy to tell which tables connect to which, since the name and column names are clear. But it's just that it's not been enforced by the DBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tinkered with this very thing. I got pretty close. This code could use some refinement. And there are certainly situations that it doesn't accommodate such as composite keys. So I offer this up as a starting point.

```
DECLARE
    @Table1           VARCHAR(35)
  , @Table1PK         VARCHAR(35)
  , @Table1JoinColumn VARCHAR(35)
  , @Table2           VARCHAR(35)
  , @Table2PK         VARCHAR(35)
  , @Table2JoinColumn VARCHAR(35)
  , @SQL              NVARCHAR(4000);
  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- fill in these four variable values for you situation...
SET @Table1 =           'replace with Table1'
SET @Table1JoinColumn = 'replace with Table1 column to join to Table2'
SET @Table2 =           'replace with Table2'
SET @Table2JoinColumn = 'replace with Table2 column to join to Table1'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- get the Primary Key column for Table1
SELECT     @Table1PK = c.name
FROM       sys.indexes       i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id
                                   AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns       c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
                                  AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE      i.is_primary_key = 1
           AND i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + @Table1);

-- get the Primary Key column for Table2
SELECT     @Table2PK = c.name
FROM       sys.indexes       i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id
                                   AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns       c ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
                                  AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE      i.is_primary_key = 1
           AND i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.' + @Table2);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##TableCounts', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TableCounts;
            
SET @SQL = '
SELECT '''
          + @Table1 + ''' AS [T1] 
        , '''+ @Table2 + ''' AS [T2] 
        , COUNT(DISTINCT a.' + @Table1PK + ')    AS [T1 Count]
        , SUM(CASE
                 WHEN b.' + @Table2PK + ' IS NULL THEN
                     1
                 ELSE
                     0
              END
             )                                    AS [T1 - T2 Count]
        , SUM(CASE
                 WHEN a.' + @Table1PK + ' IS NOT NULL and b.' + @Table2PK + ' IS NOT NULL THEN
                     1
                 ELSE
                     0
             END
             )                                   AS [T1 ' + NCHAR(1352) + ' T2 Count]
        , SUM(CASE
                 WHEN a.' + @Table1PK + ' IS NULL THEN
                     1
                 ELSE
                     0
              END
             )                                   AS [T2 - T1 Count]
        , COUNT(DISTINCT b.' + @Table2PK + ')    AS [T2 Count]
INTO ##TableCounts
FROM      dbo.' + @Table1 + ' a
FULL JOIN dbo.' + @Table2 + '    b ON a.' + @Table1JoinColumn + ' = b.' + @Table2JoinColumn + ''

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT
     *
   , CASE
         WHEN [T1 Count] = [T2 Count]
              AND [T1 - T2 Count] = 0 AND [T2 - T1 Count] = 0 THEN
             '1-1'
         WHEN [T1 Count] > [T2 Count] THEN
             'n-1'
         WHEN [T1 Count] < [T2 Count] THEN
             '1-n'
         ELSE
             'n-n'
     END AS [Cardinality]
   , CASE
         WHEN [T1 - T2 Count] > 0 THEN
             'T1'
         WHEN [T2 - T1 Count] > 0 THEN
             'T2'
         ELSE
             'None'
     END [Outer Join]
FROM ##TableCounts;
```

So for your Employee/Department relationship you would run it with these values...

```
SET @Table1 =           'Employee'
SET @Table1JoinColumn = 'departmentID'
SET @Table2 =           'Department'
SET @Table2JoinColumn = 'departmentID'
```

Since you don't have PKs you would just have to hard code `@Table1PK` and `@Table2PK` values.

Comment: this may sound stupid, but what does "Outer Join" column mean in your result?

Comment: Not stupid at all. That just means that if one of the tables is designated in the Outer Join column it has more records and that the other. You should consider using an Outer Join rather than an Inner Join in a query. Of course, that would depend on what you are trying to accomplish. For you purposes you may not care about that and could just eliminate that section.

Comment: Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @Isaac a bit surprised at the downvote. but i hope it doesn't prevent others from seeing the answer, and i couldn't upvote this answer.