# Know the type of relationships between all the tables of database in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this select from [Know relationships between all the tables of database in SQL Server stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094156/know-relationships-between-all-the-tables-of-database-in-sql-server) to find all relationships exists in my database.

```
SELECT
    fk.name 'FK Name',
    tp.name 'Parent table',
    cp.name, cp.column_id,
    tr.name 'Refrenced table',
    cr.name, cr.column_id
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tp ON fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tr ON fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cp ON fkc.parent_column_id = cp.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = cp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cr ON fkc.referenced_column_id = cr.column_id AND fkc.referenced_object_id = cr.object_id
ORDER BY
    tp.name, cp.column_id
```

But how to add type of the relationship such `M:M` `M:1`, `1:1` to the results? which sql property or column say that?

Comment: Between any 2 tables it is impossible to have a M:M relationship. To support that type of relationship you must have a third table (often referred to as an intersection table).

Answer (score 1):

There is no SQL property that tracks what you are requesting because those relationships only occur implicity, if at all.

As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292449/6789816), it is **"technically impossible"** to have a `1:1` relationship, so don't worry about that one.
`M:M` **cannot occur**, as the Primary key MUST be unique.
`M:1` **always exists** where the `1` is a unique primary key and `M` is a foreign key, given the foreign key does not also have a `UNIQUE KEY` constraint (if it does, the relationship is `1:0..1` as the previously mentioned post explains).

The closest thing I can come up with as a built-in property is `sys.key_constraints`.

#### UPDATE 2021.01.12

To clarify, while `1:1` relationships cannot exist in a Relational SQL database (again, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292449/6789816) for an explanation), they can still exist logically within code and design.

Comment: So how in typeorm they say 1:1 is possible? https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations

Comment: That is a loose 1:1 relationship defined by the program, not by the database. ORMs like this one add in constraints on the application side to enforce behavior (which means you could still INSERT a `User` directly and the DB would accept the record).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way SQL Server knows type of relationships, but here is how to discover them :

1. `1:1` : if the relationship is between a `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE FOREIGN KEY` (Unique index can be separate as well)

so have to find out out if there is unique index on the FK or it's been defined as unique fk

2. `1:M` : if the relationship is between a `PRIMARY KEY` and `FOREIGN KEY`

so if the oneside of the relationship is a primary key in that table it is a  one to many relationship.

3. `M:M` : if the relationship is between a non-unique key and non-unique foreign key.

if it doesn't any of two types above then It's many to many

Comment: Neither `1:1` nor `M:M` can exist in SQL Server.