# How to update all foreign keys in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascade

Is there a way to update one column and all foreign keys that refer to it in a database? I have a table with an id column that I would like to update with the following query:

```
UPDATE Project SET id = id + 15;
```

but I get the following error:

> Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
> Cannot update identity column 'id'.

There are a lot of tables that refer to this column, and I'm unsure which ones have an Update cascade and which ones do not.

Comment: Why do you want to update your PK? Its usually a design flaw if you do... it seems like your PK is *meaningful* which is shouldn't be. If you need a meaningful id add a separate column. If you really really do need to update your PK, its a real complex problem, involves dropping FKs and PK, temp columns, updating data, renaming columns, reinstating PK + FK... with plenty of scope to get it wrong.

Comment: This screams of being an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What you are trying to do is really horrific to do. Can it be done? Yes. Is it a good idea? Very unlikely. Is it extremely involved and takes a ton of effort and time? Yes. Instead, let's try to understand what you are trying to solve and help you find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no straightforward solution but it can be done in the following steps:

First, update child tables: You must retrieve all tables that reference your Project table and make a query to disable relation constraint check on them and then update the FK columns on each table separately.
The following query is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094156/know-relationships-between-all-the-tables-of-database-in-sql-server) that allows to make two commands: cmd1 for disabling relations and updating the FK columns and cmd2 to restore relation checks.

```
SELECT
    fk.name 'FK Name',
    tp.name 'FK table',
    cp.name 'FK column',
    'ALTER TABLE ' + tp.name + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ' + fk.name + ';' + 'update ' + tp.name + ' set ' + cp.name + ' = ' + cp.name + ' + 15;' cmd1,
    'ALTER TABLE ' + tp.name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + fk.name cmd2
FROM 
    sys.foreign_keys fk
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tp ON fk.parent_object_id = tp.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.tables tr ON fk.referenced_object_id = tr.object_id and tr.name = 'Project'
INNER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fkc ON fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns cp ON fkc.parent_column_id = cp.column_id AND fkc.parent_object_id = cp.object_id
```

you can now copy and paste the cmd1 column to update all child tables.

Second, update the parent table: Your PK is identity as the error reads. As you know updating an identity column is not possible but there is a workaround:

```
--Copy the date to a new table without an identity column
select * into Project_backup from Project union all select * from Project where 1<>1

--Update PK
update Project_backup  set id = id + 15

--Delete old data
delete from Project

--Enable identity insertion
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Project ON

--Insert into table
insert into Project (id,... /*List all columns here*/)
select * from Project_backup

--Disable identity insertion again
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Project off
```

Finally, enable relations constraints:
Using the cmd2 column of the above query now you can restore the relations.

Finally It’s done!